# Use Greasemonkey to submit a page, after checking specific radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, greasemonkey

I have to complete the form inside the website [retailedge.intel.com](http://retailedge.intel.com/) (that is not mine) several times with the correct sequence that I already know.

For example:

```
for the first question the right replay is D  
for the second question is D  
for the third D (again :))  
for the forth D (is boring, i know)  
for the fifth B (finally something new ;))
```

-- as you can see in the picture, below.

I need that when I go on the form/question page, Greasemonkey automatically sets the page with the correct sequence, so that the only things that I have to do is click the "send" button at the end :D

I mean: is it possible that Greasemonkey sets/submits the page with the radio buttons already checked on the right sequence and position?

The questions are structured like this, in the pages:

```
<li><span id="UniqueId_Q3" class="png">
        <table>
            <tr><td><span class="QuestionNumber png">3.</span></td>
                <td><span class="QuestionText png">This is the question text.</span></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </span>
    <ul>
        <li><span class="InputButton">
            <input type="radio" value="UniqueVal_1" name="UniqueName_3" id="UniqueId_Q3_1">
            <label for="UniqueId_Q3_1"><span class="png">&nbsp;a. Answer A</span></label>
        </span></li>
        <li><span class="InputButton">
            <input type="radio" value="UniqueVal_2" name="UniqueName_3" id="UniqueId_Q3_2">
            <label for="UniqueId_Q3_2"><span class="png">&nbsp;b. Answer B</span></label>
        </span></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Thank you in advance,
Teresa :)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You have to choose the form and `submit()` it:

```
document.yourformname.submit();
```

Comment: Sorry is not clear... I'm not a good informatics girl, I discover Greasmonkey and this world 72 hours ago XD. Could you be more specific. sorry again.